# After upgrading to TYPO3 8, data is not fetched from the database

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x

I have upgraded my project from `TYPO3 7.6` to `TYPO3 8.7`. The UID variable `{singleMember.uid}` is being fetched the database and displayed. But when I want to fetch `{singleMember.name}` or `{singleMember.email}`, it is always empty, even though the 'name' and 'email' columns are present in the database table.

*Controller/MemberController.php*

```
 public function listBeAction() {
 $members = $this->memberRepository->findAllSorted(array($sortField => $sortDir ));
 $members = $this->memberRepository->findAll();
 $this->view->assign('members', $members);
 }
```

*Domain/Repository/MemberRepository.php*

```
 public function findAllSorted($sorting = NULL) {
 $query = $this->createQuery();
 $query->setOrderings($sorting);
 return $query->execute();
 }
```

*Domain/Model/Member.php*

```
class Member extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {
 protected $name;
 protected $email;

public function getName() {
return $this->name;
}
public function setName($name) {
$this->name = $name;
}
public function getEmail() {
return $this->email;
}
public function setEmail($email) {
$this->email = $email;
}
}
```

Does anybody know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, one of the following line of your code is superfluous in your controller, because the second one overwrites the result of the first one:

```
$members = $this->memberRepository->findAllSorted(array($sortField => $sortDir ));
$members = $this->memberRepository->findAll();
```

The second issue is that you might have forgotten just a headline in your question, or you placed a function in the controller instead of the repository, this belongs at least in the repository:

```
public function findAllSorted($sorting = NULL) {
 $query = $this->createQuery();
 $query->setOrderings($sorting);
 return $query->execute();
 }
```

The model class still has two issues too:

1. the namespace might be missing, it's the 2nd line in the file
   usually and looking like this:
   `namespace Vendor\ExtensionName\Domain\Model;`
   , where `Vendor` and `ExtensionName` have to be replaced by your own values.
2. Annotations are missing, they are used to validate the fields even they are notated as php-comments.

So all together your model file has to look like this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ExtensionName\Domain\Model; // replace 'vendor' and 'ExtensionName' by your own values

class Member extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{

    /**
     * name
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * email
     * 
     * @var string
     * @validate EmailAddress
     *
     * @see \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\AbstractValidator
     * @see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/configuration_object/04-Administration/Validators/Index.html
     * @important never accepts umlauts in the complete email-address, validate it individually to allow those addresses!
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * Returns the name
     * 
     * @return string $name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name
     * 
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the email
     * 
     * @return string $email
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the email
     * 
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email= $email;
    }

}
```

**To your question:**

The reasons are quite unclear why the objects never return the desired values, also because you never provided the code of the whole extension.
Here are thinkable reasons:

1. The methods `findAll()` and/or `findAllSorted` in the repository class are coded to return only the uid of each record. This case is very unlikely but I just mention it.
2. The fields are not configured in `ext_tables.sql` and `Configuration/TCA/tx_yourextension_domain_model_member.php` (replace tx_**yourextension**_... by your value).

Further reasons might be thinkable, but perhaps you check first the points I mentioned and give feedback. If required you can give more information and I can extend my answer.